# How to view the queries to a Postgres database in real time?

Tags: postgresql, testing, capybara, deadlock

I have a Capybara test which causes a deadlock. In order to troubleshoot the deadlock and see what exactly is going on, I would like to have a way to see what queries are executed by the test in real time. Is there a way to do this?

I have found [this article](http://chrismiles.info/systemsadmin/databases/articles/viewing-current-postgresql-queries/), but if I am not mistaken, this will only store the queries in a table, which I need to query myself. Isn't there a way to see in terminal something like:

```
PID 1234 -> SELECT xxxx FROM xxxx WHERE xxxxx
PID 5678 -> SELECT xxxx FROM xxxx WHERE xxxxx
...
```

?

Comment: You can turn on logging of the statements so that they are written to the Postgres logfile: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry I've missed this reading through the question. Also as I see Alex is looking for deadlooks so there is no need to log all queries is enough to query the table from this article when deadlook occurs. All looked queries have to be there.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 10x for the hint. You suggestion led me to [this post](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/configuring-logging-for-postgresapp/) which accomplishes exactly what I want.

Comment: Querying pg_stat_activity should provide the information you are looking for, isn't it? Lock-specific info can be found in pg_locks - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/view-pg-locks.html.